# Is my textbook definition of multidimensional CLT incorrect?

Tags: probability, statistics, definition, central-limit-theorem

From All of Statistics by Wasserman, 2nd Edition:

[image: definition part 1]
[image: definition part 2]

There are two ways I can interpret how $\mu$ is defined:

1. The $\mu$ defined is the expected value of a single one of the $X_i$ vectors. But then $\overline{X} - \mu$ is subtracting the means of 1 specific random vector from the sample mean of every other random vector, which makes no sense.
2. The $\mu$ defined is actually the expected values of each of the different $X_i$ vectors, but then I'd expect it to be defined as $\mathbb{E}(X_1), \ldots, \mathbb{E}(X_n)$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(X_{1i}), \ldots, \mathbb{E}(X_{ni})$. Even if I assume that's what Wasserman meant though, $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$ is itself a vector, and $\overline{X} - \mu$ is undefined because you can't subtract a vector of vectors from a vector.

Am I missing something? Basically, I don't see how this type checks.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense to subtract the mean of $X_1$ from $\bar X$? All of the $X_i$ have the same distribution!

Comment: $\bar X$ is a vector, each $E(X_i)$ is a vector, so a vector of those is a vector of vectors. Also, they don't subtract those two -- they subtract $E(X_{ki})$, not $E(X_i)$ based on how they define $\mu$.

Comment: The reason for introducing the double subscripts is to be able to talk about components of the multi-dimensional random variable as well as the *sample instances*.  It can get confusing because the expected value of the *sample mean* is the same (component by component) as *population mean* (expected value of the multi-dimensional random variable $X$).  However the *variance* of sample means is not the same as the population variance (because the sample mean variance decreases with increasing sample size).

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted for an honest question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\mu$ is correct. It is a vector and equal to $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ (note that $X_1$ is a vector of length $k$).

Perhaps you are misunderstanding the definition of $\bar{X}$. It is also a vector of length $k$, and obtained by summing the vectors $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and dividing by $n$.

Since $\bar{X}$ and $\mu$ are both vectors of length $k$, the subtraction makes sense.

The $j$th entry of $\bar{X} - \mu$ is
$\bar{X}_j - \mu_j = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{ji} - \mathbb{E}[X_{j1}]$.

Comment: I think maybe my confusion is this: $E(X_1)$ is a vector because $X_1$ is a vector. But the sample mean of $X_1$ is a scalar. I would expect to see in the formula a subtraction of population mean (vector) from sample mean (scalar) in order to demonstrate them getting arbitrarily close together. But you can't subtract a vector from a scalar. Somehow we leapt to it being ok to instead subtract the expectation of individual elements of one of the random vectors. I can accept that since they are IID subtracting $E(X_1)$ is as good as any $E(X_i)$, but I don't see why we are allowed to at all.

Comment: @JosephGarvin As I mentioned, I think you are misunderstanding what $\bar{X}_1$ means. It is **not** the sample mean of the elements of the vector $X_1$; rather, it is the mean of the first components of the vectors $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.

Comment: You are correct I was misunderstanding $\bar{X}_1$. I think it is correct to say it is the sample mean of the $X_1i$s inside each $X_i$.